# Powershell 5 clipboard - manually pasting "complex" clipboard content doesn't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I just installed Win10 on my notebook and took a first look at all the new commandlets.

While using simple text like:

```
PS C:\Users\SudoSandwich> $do = echo "sad"
PS C:\Users\SudoSandwich> $do | Set-Clipboard
```

and manually pasting it in Notepad for example works just fine, I'm having trouble with some more "complex" clipboard content.
Let's use `dir | Set-Clipboard`.
I know that in the console you have to use `Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList` to get it back, but what about pasting the results of `dir` into notepad? Appearantly pasting is disabled in that case.

Anyone figured out why this doesn't work yet? The oldschool way of selecting the output in the console and pasting it in notepad still works fine.

Comment: `dir|Out-String|Set-Clipboard`

Comment: That's it. Sometimes it can be so simple. Thanks m8

Do you want to set this as an answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Out-String` cmdlet to convert any complex object to the text you normally see on console. Then you can copy that text to clipboard:

```
dir | Out-String | Set-Clipboard
```

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that pipe output for dir is object rather than a plain text that set-clipboard can't just copy, you need to kind of expand or convert it into a string before you copy it to clipboard, try this [string[]] (dir) | Set-Clipboard

Comment: yes. like everything else in PS the clipboard is also an object.that goes into the right direction. Together with the -f format operator I could get the output I desire.
My hopes where however, to get exactly the same output like you would see in the console or by manually selecting and copying it to notepad